# Jquery element.css method is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically create div element from function in object but i get an error

```
index.html:23 Uncaught TypeError: toolbardiv.css is not a function
```

I can't a problem in my code explain me what is going wrong

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var toolbar = {
                        render:function(){
                            var toolbardiv = document.createElement("div");
                            toolbardiv.css({'class':'draggable box'});
                            toolbardiv.id = "toolbardiv";
                            toolbardiv.appendTo('#container');
                        },
                        init: function(){},
                        createButton: function(){

                        },
                        createText: function(){}
                    };
                    toolbar.render();


                $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
            });
```

Comment: either you're using jquery or you're not. `var toolbardiv = $('<div/>'); ...`

Comment: The problem in your code is that `createElement()` aptly returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object. You have to wrap that element in a jQuery object in order to apply `css()` to it.

Comment: You can also set the class by simple javascript: toolbardiv.classList = 'draggable box'

Comment: jQuery objects are a ***superset*** of native DOM objects. That is, they contain additional methods outside of that of the native DOM methods. `.css()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be intertwining jQuery and Javascript, which if you are using libraries that may be based off of jQuery could cause issues (as the libraries might expect jQuery objects as opposed to traditional DOM elements).

You can simplify some of your code a great deal, especially the creating of your `<div>` by using an all jQuery-based syntax :

```
// This will create your element with its attributes and add it to your container
$("<div id='toolbardiv' class='draggable box' />").appendTo('#container');
```

which adding to your existing function would look like the following :

```
$(function(){
      // Define your toolbar
      var toolbar = {
           // Render your element
           render:function(){
                $("<div id='toolbardiv' class='draggable box' />").appendTo('#container');
           },
           init: function(){},
           createButton: function(){},
           createText: function(){}
      };
      // Call your render method
      toolbar.render();
      // Wire up your elements as "draggable"
      $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntaxes mix jQuery and DOM. Try this:

`$(toolbardiv).css({'class':'draggable box'});`